# audio service is not running windows 8.1 Lenovo y510

Tags: window

My lenovo y510 was recently updated windows 8.1 and the audio stop function also the window media player . AVG was uninstall but this did not work can you help me?

Comment: what does AVG have anything to do with your audio?

Answer (score -1):

It's been listed that avg sometimes quarantines the audio file. Restore the virus vault,uninstall avg and try again.